# Always have much xcrun error in xnu installing(OSX 10.8.3)

Tags: installation, xcrun, xnu

i searched much websites to install the xnu kernel. however, there are some errors when i was installing xnu. 

Xcode version: 4.6 (installed command line tool)

XNU version: xnu-2050.22.13

dtrace version: dtrace-96

here is the **ERRORS**:
**xcrun: error: unable to find utility "ctfconvert", not a developer tool or in PATH

xcrun: error: unable to find utility "ctfmerge", not a developer tool or in PATH**

i used the "make install" to install the dtrace, but it also showing the error.
Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing dependencies. The long story short version, is you need to first get and make dtrace-tools:

```
$ curl http://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/dtrace/dtrace-96.tar.gz > dt.tar.gz
$ tar zxvf dt.tar.gz
$ cd dtrace-96
$ mkdir -p obj sym dst
$ xcodebuild install -target ctfconvert -target ctfdump -target ctfmerge \
ARCHS="i386 x86_64" SRCROOT=$PWD OBJROOT=$PWD/obj SYMROOT=$PWD/sym \
DSTROOT=$PWD/dst
```

Comment: Couldn't submit this as an edit, so just an FYI.  The last line should be DSTROOT=$PWD/dst.  You have an extra 'u' in there.

Comment: @Eeyore, I believe it is just a typo send went for edit. The original author fortunately is still around and can take another look if needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need the latest version of apple's dtools utilities. The easiest way to install the tools is with MacPorts. If you don't have MacPorts, you can download it [here](http://www.macports.org/install.php).

With MacPorts installed, open Terminal, and run "sudo port install dtrace"

XNU should compile.